# understanding intersection of a set

Tags: elementary-set-theory

The definition I was giving of the intersection of a non-empty set A is that
$\cap A= \{y |(\forall x\in A)y \in x\}$ and the definition of inclusion if that $A \subseteq B \iff \forall t(t\in A \rightarrow t\in B)$.

I read that $\cap A \subseteq X $ for all $X \in  A$ but from the definitions i wrote I don't understand how to justify that.

Answer (score 2):

It's quite simple. To show $\bigcap A \subseteq X$ for all $X \in A$, we simply assume $X \in A$ and $y \in \bigcap A$. We use the definitions to conclude that $y \in X$. This shows $\bigcap A \subseteq X$, which holds for arbitrary $X \in A$, which is what we want to prove.

So, let us suppose $y \in \bigcap A$ and $X \in A$. Then, by definition of $\bigcap A$, $y \in x$ for all $x \in A$. In particular, if we take $x = X \in A$, then we have $y \in X$, as desired.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Got it, thank you!